# "New Feature" indicator overlay for the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If a webapp like Confluence or jenkins has been updated, a box will appear which explains the new stuff.

Is there a little toolbox or something, which I could use to generate something like this? I am think about an overlay or something where I can put in the new features. Much better would be a little framework, where I can highlight new features for the user immediately.

I know, this can easily be done manually, but I am still interested if there's something useful which is already ready to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/).  Just include the js and css files and add data-step and data-intro to your code:

```
<h1 data-intro="Hello all! :) This project's called Intro.js." data-step="1">
    Intro<span style="font-weight: normal;">.js</span>
</h1>
```

[image]